# Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http addValidator isValid

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my code

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$adapter->addValidator('Extension', false,
                array('extension' => 'exe, php, pl, js, html, htm', 'case' => false));
if (!$adapter->isValid())
{
   return 'ERROR';
}
```

When I try to upload jpg or txt file I get 'ERROR' string. Looks like $adapter->isValid() return false. Should it return true?

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to upload a `jpg` or `txt` file, but neither of those extensions are allowed in the list.  You are only allowing `exe`, `php`, `pl`, `js`, `html`, or `htm`.

There is also a small problem with the way the extensions are set in the array having spaces between them.  I inspected the values and ZF had the list of extensions you supplied, but every one except the first was preceded by a space.

Either of the following two options will work:

```
// array method
$adapter->addValidator('Extension', false,
                       array('txt', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'exe',
                             'php', 'pl', 'js', 'html', 'htm',
                             'case' => false));

// or

// string method
$adapter->addValidator('Extension', false,
                       'txt,jpg,jpeg,exe,php,pl,js,html,htm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code and you can add a message on error too

```
$adapter->addValidator(
       'extension', 
       false, 
       array(
            'jpg,jpeg,png,avi,mov,mpeg,wmv', 
            'messages' => array(
                               Zend_Validate_File_Extension::FALSE_EXTENSION => 
                               'Invalid format must be jpg,jpeg,png,avi,mov,wmv or mpeg.'
                                )
             )
        );
```